# Did the meaning of fair change?

Tags: language-evolution

I have been reading a bunch of fiction books, such as the Lord of the Rings series and similar. They are definitely modern books, but use a literary language and constructs to give a bit of historical accents.

In these books, I've often encountered fair associated with beautiful, special, astonishing, perhaps magical. And I realized we have fairy in the language, perhaps related.

In the standard English, for me, as a non-native speaker, fair means honest, correct. We have fair coin, which is not an extraordinary coin, but merely a balanced coin.

Did the meaning of fair change over time, or is this just another use in literature?

Comment: We still use both meanings ... when we say *fair weather*, we do not mean *honest weather*, but something more like *beautiful* or *pleasant weather*.

Comment: Every word changes meaning over time. (Semantic change)

Comment: Language is ever-changing and sometimes a word metamorphosizes-- Fair"  turns into "foul" and "foul turns into "fair"-- This example is far-fetched, but I couldn't resist.

Comment: Where is 'fair change' used? Could you give us the whole sentence?

Answer (score 0):

It is a long-established meaning. Part of the large etymology is:

> Old English *fæger* "pleasing to the sight" (of persons, objects, places ...), "beautiful, handsome, attractive"; of weather, "bright, clear, pleasant; not rainy"; also in late Old English "morally good".
>
> Referring to complexion or hair colour it is from around mid middle ages 1200, faire, in contrast to *browne*.
>
>  [[Etymonline]](https://www.etymonline.com/word/fair)

There are many other early uses too long to repeat here. At the time of writing, [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/fair) is useful.